# Dynamic code analysis for C++

Tags: c++, code-analysis

Is there an open source and (relatively) simple-to-use [dynamic code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis) tool for C++ code?

Something like [IBM Purify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Purify) (memory corruption detection, memory leak detection, application performance profiling, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

The software that is widely used (on Linux at least) is [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). It has a lot of sub tools used to do what you are looking for.

There is also [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) which is a GUI frontend to the profiling tool of Valgrind, AKA [Cachegrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind#Other_tools).

Comment: This seems to be a great tool, but the only thing is that it appears to be limited to Linux platforms only. I'm writing code in a windows environment. Am I doomed? :O

Comment: @user181218: sorry I have less experience on windows tools concerning this area. For basic memory corruption I've used ElectricFence a long time ago. Check for Duma as stated in @eddy pronk answer, it seems to be a fork that works on windows ...And yes of course you are doomed ;)

Comment: Valgrind is terrible tool, with a lot of false positives.

Comment: @user6039980: Yes it has. But you can suppress false positives with suppressions files.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Duma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duma/) (Detect Unintended Memory Access).

Comment: +1: I've used ElectricFence from which duma seems to have forked. Thanks for the link ...

Answer (score 1):

Try [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). It is not as powerful as [IBM Purify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Purify), but it works quite fine...

Comment: Valgrind reports false positives, shouldn't be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

[CodeCompass](https://github.com/Ericsson/CodeCompass) is quite good as well.

Although it has quite the dependencies compared to [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) and [Duma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duma/), it's a quality analysis tool.