# C++ Dynamic Code Analysis tools for Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dynamic-analysis

i was searching for a tool that detect (Memory Leaks,Memory Corruption, ...) at run-time in VS for C++

and i found this : [Dynamic code analysis for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933699/dynamic-code-analysis-c)

unfortunately most of them running under linux so i ask for tools running to VS or at least for Windows

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [`MSYS`](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or [`cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) allow you to use linux tools natively on windows.

Comment: i know Cygwin ,but i wonder isn't there any tool run in windows..
did microsoft forget to invent something like that !!

Comment: The linked question includes [`duma`](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) which runs on windows. re: Microsoft: they do it for money. Open source does it for love (and to scratch itches).

Comment: UMDH is not bad.[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560206(VS.85).aspx)] . it heped me;

Comment: Current link for UMDH: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I know for the windows platform is [DrMemory](http://www.drmemory.org/).

It works fast and it helped me a lot in my critical/legacy MFC C++ code even if it currently targets 32-bit applications only.

Let me know your favorite parameters! I recommend you to start with the simple "-top_stats -light".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check out [Runtime Checker](http://www.runtimechecker.com/). It is designed to help detect memory leaks in Windows C++ applications.

Comment: the link seems broken

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for answers to this problem as well.

One that I found is [DevPartner Bounds Checker](http://www.borland.com/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Devpartner-Studio) (The link is for DevPartner Studio. It is possible to buy just the bounds checker component, however). I was able to get some good results from it, but I also had problems with its instrumenting tool crashing on my particular codebase. Their tech support was pretty bad. YMMV.

Another is [Parasoft Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/product/insure/). This tool has been around a long time, and the demos looked good. I haven't had much time to use it yet, but it seems hopeful.

Both of these are commercial products with sales teams and technical support. Prices tend to be negotiated with a salesman.