# C++: Statistics to identify raw pointers usage

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to replace the raw pointers that are in a project with `std::shared_ptr` and I have around 4500 pointer declarations.
So before I start to replace them, I would like to know if there are some tools or some other utilities that I can use to do a study of how much time I need to do it.
In particular I am wondering if there are some consistent tools for Static and Dynamic analisys of pointer usage (for Unix, Linux or Windows) in order to understand what is the workload of the task involved and eventually have some support during this task.

Comment: In general, prefer replacing owning pointers with `std::unique_ptr` whenever possible, only use `std::shared_ptr` as a last resort.  If the pointer is non-owning, use a reference or raw pointer.  Raw pointers aren't bad.  _Owning_ raw pointers are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don`t know if it will help, but I found this : [Dynamic code analysis for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933699/dynamic-code-analysis-for-c)

If by any chance your project can be run under xCode, you have a tool called instruments that is awesome.